# How to take a text file (containing html format) to show in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have an html table stored in a txt file. I would like to show this table through iframe. Is this possible? Are there better ways to achieve this?

just to help give more detail on this... there is a program that updates the text file with html format. Currently i'm just copy and pasting it to the destination. However, if I can get an html file to display the table it will save me time.

I want it the table to be interpreted with no tags as shown below:

ServerName-01  custom_URL1, Custom_URL2

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier achieving this with an XML file not a txt file